# How to count table rows using class name in Watir?

Tags: ruby, rspec, watir, watir-webdriver

I want to count all table rows which class name is `subjectField` and to stop counting if some row's class name is `separator`.

HTML:

```
<div id="household" class="block">

<div class="block_title"> … </div>
<table class="color_table">
    <thead> … </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="first_row"> … </tr>
        <tr class="subjectField" style="display:none"> … </tr>
        <tr class="odd_row"> … </tr>
        <tr class="subjectField" style="display:none"> … </tr>
        <tr class="even_row"> … </tr>
        <tr class="subjectField" style="display:none"> … </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="separator" rowspan="1" colspan="10">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_row"> … </tr>
        <tr class="subjectField" style="display:none"> … </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

My code:

```
def countRows
    @subjects = 0
    @f.div(:id => 'household').table(:class => 'color_table').tbody.trs.find do |tr|            
    if tr.td(:class => "separator").exists? == true
        break
    elsif tr(:class => "subjectField").exists? == true
        @subjects = @subjects + 1
    end         
end
return subjects
end
```

This does not work for me. It says that `tr` on **line 6** is *undefined method*.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue 1 - Checking row class**

You are passing `tr` parameters, which is why Ruby thinks it is a method. In this case, `tr` is actually an element that is selected for the current iteration of the loop. To check the current tr's class attribute, the `elsif` statement should be:

```
elsif tr.class_name == "subjectField"
```

**Issue 2 - Iterating rows**

Note that you will also have a problem with the line:

```
@f.div(:id => 'household').table(:class => 'color_table').tbody.trs.find
```

The `find` method will iterate through the trs until the block evaluates as true. Since the block will always evaluate to true or break, you will only get 0 or 1 subjects. Use `each` instead:

```
@f.div(:id => 'household').table(:class => 'color_table').tbody.trs.each
```

**Putting it together**

Putting the above fixes together, the method could be written as:

```
def countRows
  @subjects = 0
  table = @f.div(:id => 'household').table(:class => 'color_table')
  table.tbody.trs.each do |tr|            
    break if tr.td(:class => "separator").exists? == true

    @subjects += 1 if tr.class_name == "subjectField"
  end         
  @subjects
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I still have a problem with this case.
The thing is that when I use 'exists?' then it searches it from the whole page but I need to check it only in the certain 'tr'.

Using 'if tr.td(:class => "separator").exists? == true' I want it to check if certain tr has class named separator and if not then go to the next condition.

Comment: The code `tr.td(:class => "separator").exists?` will only check that the td exists in the current tr. The problem you are seeing is due to how you are iterating the trs - it should be `each` instead of `find`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i would do that (untested code):

```
def count_rows
  @f.div(:id => 'household')
    .table(:class => 'color_table')
    .trs
    .take_while {|row| !row.td(:class => "separator").exists? }
    .select {|row| row.class_name =~ /subjectField/}
    .size
end
```

Comment: @Seda, are you sure this answers your problem? For the sample html, this returns 4 and I believe you want 3. The take_while block is assuming that the separator cell is within a subjectField row, which is not true.

Comment: Yes, it returned 4. I think the problem is that driver is trying to find the separator class in the trs with class 'subjectField'. He can't find it there, that's why the return is 4, instead of 3.
The first answer suits for my problem better. But thank you anyway for trying to help! :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry - i misread the original problem. I've edited the code to work correctly :)